# Convert absolute classname in `use`

Tags: php, namespaces

I've ~1'000 php files with absolute classnames:

```
<?php

namespace MyProject\Core;

class Server {
  // ...
  $o = new \MyProject\Input\Parser();
  // ...
  $o->foo(new \MyProject\Input\Args(['foo', 'bar']));
  // ...
  \MyProject\Foo\Bar::baz();
}
```

Does exist ready to use `php`/`bash`/`...` script to convert them to use `use` instruction ? Or simple way to do it ? Where output will be:

```
<?php

namespace MyProject\Core;

use MyProject\Input\Parser;
use MyProject\Input\Args;
use MyProject\Foo\Bar;

class Server {
  // ...
  $o = new Parser();
  // ...
  $o->foo(new Args(['foo', 'bar']));
  // ...
  Bar::baz();
}
```

Comment: How many files do you have?

Comment: A bit more less 1'000

Comment: [This might be worth a look](https://github.com/QafooLabs/php-refactoring-browser), though I haven't used it, but `php refactor.phar optimize-use <file>` seems to do what you want: importing FQN with `use` statements. Just a simple bash script that passes all `.php` files to this command will automate all the refactoring for you